# Identify the children's fantasy book where a boy lives among sea otters

Tags: story-identification, magic

When I was in middle school, about twelve years old (around 1989), I remember reading a fantasy novel recommended to me by our school librarian and have tried for years to remember its name.

The only detail of the story that has stuck with me is that at some point **the protagonist breaks his arm and is found/helped/healed by sea otters.  He lives among them for a time, learning to swim and hold his breath for extreme amounts of time.** I think he may have also learned magic, and there may have been dragons involved.

Does anybody know what this book is called?

Comment: This might be a longshot, but if the Accepted Answer really doesn't jog your memory, you might want to look up references on the South Park "Go God Go!" arc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sounds like [Nightpool](http://www.librarything.com/work/525618) by [Shirley Rousseau Murphy](http://www.librarything.com/author/murphyshirleyroussea), the first book in the [Dragonbards trilogy](http://www.librarything.com/series/Dragonbards). It is currently out of print, but is available as an eBook on various platforms, including Kindle and Nook.

Synopsis:

> Injured in battle with the Dark Raiders, sixteen-year-old Tebriel is healed by a colony of talking otters and sets out to fight the Dark and its forces of evil in the world of Tirror.

Comment: That could be it. I was hoping the title, author, or cover would help me remember more. I've requested a copy from my library to confirm n

Comment: Just finished re-reading this, and was amazed at how little of the book I remembered.  Nothing jogged my memory.  The details in my question were there (except he broke his leg, not arm).  I'm now onto the sequels.